# button click on website using powershell

Tags: html, powershell

i am adding user id and password to website and trying to login to site. in below code i am not able to click on the Login button i tried click submit but not able to click. can any one please help me

```
$username = "abcd" 
$password = "abc" 
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate("https://wss.mahadiscom.in/wss/wss?uiActionName=getCustAccountLogin") 
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100} 
$ie.document.getElementById("loginId").value= "$username" 
$ie.document.getElementById("password").value = "$password" 
$fs = $ie.document.getElementById("loginButton")
$fs.click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of native `getElementById` method, use `IHTMLDocument3_getElementById`:

```
$username="myname"
$password="mypass"
$url = "http://wss.mahadiscom.in/wss/wss?uiActionName=getCustAccountLogin"
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate($url)
while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }
$ie.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("loginId").value = $username
$ie.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("password").value = $password
$ie.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("loginButton").click()
```

It will show [an alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpbRH.png) stating "Login Name and Password combination is incorrect.".

It's working on my machine having IE11 and WIN10. There are 3 important changes in above code:

- Using `http` rather than `https` because of IE problem with certificate of that site at the time which I tried the site.
- Checking `Busy` property of IE to check if IE is busy, then wait for it.
- Using `IHTMLDocument3_getElementById` instead of `getElementById`.

Comment: it is giving error  Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01B6
At E:\electricbilllogin.ps1:11 char:1
+ $ie.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("loginButton").click()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException

Comment: On my machine, it shows [an alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpbRH.png) stating "Login Name and Password combination is incorrect." And the key point for me is using `IHTMLDocument3_getElementById` instead of `getElementById`. Are you sure you copied and run exactly above code which I shared?

Comment: yes exact the same code. any pointer why it is giving error then

Comment: If I use `getElementById`, I receive the same error, but using `IHTMLDocument3_getElementById` everything works fine.

Comment: If you pay attention, I'm using `http` url rather than `https` because of IE problem with certificate of that site. So please make sure you copy the exact code from my answer and paste in ISE window and run it.

Comment: yes exact same code with http but same error. also tried with https but same error.

Comment: It's strange, there are 3 important point in the script, using `http` in this case, using `while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }` and calling `IHTMLDocument3_getElementById`. That's what I can share and I can confirm it's working here on my machine. I'm using IE11 on WIN10.

Comment: it gives error on command 
    $ie.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("loginButton").click()  same configuration here. also PSVersion is 5.1.16299.98

Comment: The error is not related to PS, it comes from IE, but for your information my ps version is `5.1.16299.98` and IE `version 11.98.16299.0 update version 11.48`.

Comment: my IE version is 11.125.16299.0

Comment: do we have similar code in C# any pointer on this will helpful

Comment: There are couple of examples around using WebBrowser control in C# Windows Forms. Since it's working on my machine using C# or Powershell, the only thing that comes to my mind is about Compatibility mode settings of IE.

Comment: i reset IE and re run again now it is not giving error but still not able to click it is giving `[DBG]: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>> $ie.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("loginButton").click

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
void click ()  `   `[DBG]: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>> $ie.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("loginButton").click()
System.__ComObject`

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: i run on different machine having IE version 11.15.16299.0 and it worked but latest version giving same issue. don't know what changed in latest version

Comment: It's strange, I'll check it on new version if I received the update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161430/discussion-between-farhan-and-reza-aghaei).

Comment: @Farhan I posted an example in chat for you.